# MVP or MVVM framework for both WPF and .NET CF 3.5 development

Tags: wpf, model-view-controller, windows-mobile, prism, mvp

I am creating a draft architecture outline for a disconnected client-server platform, that involves multiple different client types. I need to support: web clients, desktop workstations and mobile devices (WM 6.x now and Android later).

I am searching for a MVP or MVVM based framework that would let me to reuse as much of the code and architecture as possible between clients, while:

- using WPF for desktop development
- using .NET CF 3.5 for Windows Mobile development

This framework does not obviously need to support Android, however I am considering [Mono for Android](http://mono-android.net/) to develop the Android client (for easier maintenance of the whole platform), so portability would have been an added asset.

So far I ruled out:

- Prism (does not support WM based mobile devices - Windows Phone 7 only)
- [MVC#](http://www.mvcsharp.org/) (does not support WPF)

I would appreciate any hints that would aid in researching the subject further.

Comment: Prism is more of a application composition framework than an MVVM framework. It has a few things that make MVVM simpler, but not as much as some other frameworks.

Comment: @Sebastian Zaklada Have you figured it out. Now i have a requirement for the same thing

Answer (score 2):

These MVVM Frameworks work with Windows Phone 7:

1. [Caliburn Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/)
2. [MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) (it doesn't advertise it, but I've been to a demo where it was used on WP7)
3. [ReactiveUI](http://reactiveui.net/) (Uses the Reactive Extensions for .NET)

My personal favorite is ReactiveUI, but if you've never used the Reactive Extensions it can be a brain burner at first.

As for UI Composition (you mentioned Prism), there aren't a lot of options, mostly due to reflection restrictions on the phone. I have seen an article where someone got basic MEF working on the phone and MEF is probably all most people need in this situation.  You can check out that article [here](http://www.damonpayne.com/post/2010/06/25/MEF-For-Windows-Phone-7.aspx).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but what I am really looking for is Windows Mobile 6.x compatibility - PDT devices de facto standard is WM 6.x, Windows Phone 7 is not meant to be used to develop business applications

Comment: Still, +1 for mentioning ReactiveUI. This is the Nth time I stumble upon it and perhaps it is the right time to finally start using it.

Comment: @Sebastian Zaklada: Really sorry about that... I missed that requirement. That's a really tough requirement you've got there. Interested to know if you figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, this would be a custom Framework with a mix of UI Processes for different client types. The business logic or entities can definitely be reused to suit the needs of the view.

Comment: This is something that I would like to avoid. I do not want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

I did the same research and I concluded the following (which I did not implement yet):

- **There aren't any open source MVVM frameworks that support .NETCF**. You
  can only find MVC or MVP, but not MVVM.

**Suggestion:** get the source code of an Open Source MVVM framework that supports the Full/Desktop .NET, and see if you can adapt it(so that it recompiles) to the .NETCF. I found the following two, which also support the other platforms that you mentioned:

- [MVVM FX for Windows Forms and Visual WebGUI - Home](https://mvvmfx.codeplex.com/Wikipage?ProjectName=mvvmfx#)
- [MugenMvvmToolkit](https://github.com/MugenMvvmToolkit/MugenMvvmToolkit)

Other than that, I don't see any other way of doing this.

HTH,

Answer (score -1):

MVVM wouldn't make much sense in Windows Mobile + .NETCF since you don't have INotifyPropertyChanged and implementing Model-View-Presenter in WPF or any INotifiyPropertyChanged supported framework wouldn't be as effective as Model-View-ViewModel

You can share assets between the full and compact framework by moving most of the business logic into a seperate class library (or several) that target the .NETCF. You can reference a .NETCF library from a full framework project, but not the other way around.

Check out this very good article by Daniel Moth describing how to share assets between the compact and full framework:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/msdnmag/issues/07/07/ShareCode/default.aspx

Comment: .NETCF5 has the INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: @Christian Resma Helle: INotifyPropertyChanged is just an interface. If you go the path of implementing your own MVVM framework, couldn't you just implement it by yourself, if it's not there?